# How to put canvas over canvas at fix place in parent canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, pdf.js

I developed wrapper of Fabric JS canvas over firefox PDF viewer. I want to put canvas over a canvas and fix it at bottom and send others to sign in that specific place.
Can anybody help me how I can achieve this task? Which JS library should I use?